# Where do I go to upgrade my ship?

Tags: x-rebirth

Where can I go to purchase ship upgrade components in X Rebirth?  Can I only do that at specific stations or can I run into an equipment dealer anywhere?

Comment: With the previous installments of the game you would go to a trading station. Might be something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far, I have been able to find various mechanics on board stations that sells me upgrades such as shields, engines, weapons, and sensors.

Answer (score 0):

You need a mechanic.  Often in stations with a Spanner symbol.  Click on icon before docking and it says whether there is one.

Answer (score 0):

There's option to upgrade your other ships in squad if you find shipyards with compatible ship designs. But upgrade here does not seem to be able to upgrade engine, shield etc. It would however upgrade turrets count, shield projector count etc.